# How to use the latest Java from NetBeans 7.0 on TextMate?

Tags: macos, java, textmate, netbeans

Several months ago I downloaded NetBeans 7.0 with All Supported technologies from [this page](http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html).

I find myself on TextMate more often instead of NB when experimenting Java codes, I open NB maybe once in every 2 weeks or a month, but I open TextMate everyday, anyway. One feature that I love from TextMate is `command r` to compile and run.

But the thing is it's using `java version "1.5.0_28". Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_28-b04-382-9M3326). Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.5.0_28-157, mixed mode, sharing)` from my `Mac OS X 10.5.8`

How can I make TextMate running Java from NB 7.0 instead?

I asked [a question on Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17268/how-to-grep-recursive-unix-tree-results-along-with-each-tree-node) regarding the complete NB's Java path but I still don't get the executable Java I'm looking for. Does anyone familiar with Java and NetBeans have any ideas?

Update 2: Thanks for the awesome comments, guys!

For @romainl, now how can I add this `Java SE 6` to my path `$JAVA_HOME` at my `.profile` when I don't know where its path is being located? My Java Preferences is this

[image: My Java Preferences]

For @slhck, now how can I know `Java SE 6` **path** from my Activity Monitor? hmm this app is like `UNIX top`, eh?

[image: My Activity Monitor]

Comment: I guess TextMate will use the binaries from its PATH. Go to *Preferences -- Advanced -- Shell Variables* and see what the PATH says. Most probably, the `java` TextMate uses will be `/usr/bin/java`. You would need to add the path of Netbeans' `java` binaries in front of TextMate's PATH, separated by a colon (`:`). If that's enough to make it work, I unfortunately don't know.

Comment: @slhck, thanks for the comment. You're right, but the thing I'm not familiar with java path from NB, I searched many times but failed to see where the executable java is, and also even if I did that already I wonder if I can also call related Java environment/lib? from TextMate just like when we use NB and Java.

Comment: Maybe you can check in *Activity Monitor.app* which `java` is open when you run it from Netbeans. I'm not familiar with NB at all though.

Comment: NB doesn't use its own runtime. Did you use `/Applications/Utilities/Java Preferences.app`? It will show what versions of Java are available and active. NB 7.0 doesn't work with Java SE 5, it needs 6 so if it is running fine you'll probably have both in the list. If yes you may uncheck 5 and see what happens. Depending how the Java runtime is called from TextMate's Java bundle you will probably need to add/edit the `$JAVA_HOME` environment variable in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`. It's possible that the runtime's path is hardcoded in the bundle (a few bundles do that), did you take a look?

Comment: @romainl and slhck, I've just updated my Question to my latest progress answering your comments. What should I do now to get `Java SE 6` **path**?

Comment: In the 1st screen it's written "Drag to change the preferred order". You should reverse the order of the 2 first items or, if you are positive there will be no side effect, uncheck the two `SE 5`. After it's done, `java -version` in a new terminal window should show that you run Java SE 6. After relaunching TextMate, do `Cmd-r`. Did it work? If not, the problem may come from the Java bundle and you'll have to search for some hardlinked or hardcoded reference to the old Java SE.

Comment: About Activity Monitor, you can hit the "Inspect" button to see what files are used by the selected app.

Comment: The `/usr/bin/java` returned by `which java` is an alias to `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Commands/java`. Look around for the correct path to Java SE 6, but I suspect you won't need it.

Comment: @romainl you should've written your enlightenment as an answer, man, so that I can accept and upvote it :-) It's working!! I'm so happy. Oh and about TextMate, I didn't even relaunch it, it just worked after I dragged and uncheck the two `SE 5`

Comment: I think I just discovered how to game stackoverflow: you just have to goof around in the comments and, once the solution is found, you post the answer. I'm such a winner !!!! OK, seriously I didn't know EXACTLY how to solve your problem. I'll post the answer anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(note: the solution was found in the question's comments, this is an edited version and probably not a "real" answer by SU's standards)*

NetBeans doesn't use its own runtime, instead it uses the runtime currently active on your machine.

NetBeans 7.0 doesn't work with Java SE 5, it needs Java SE 6. If NetBeans works it means that you have Java SE 6 installed on your Mac.

Since `java -version` says that the default Java SE is Java SE 5 you'll have to launch `/Applications/Utilities/Java Preferences.app`, it shows what versions of Java are available and active.

There is a little note under the list of available runtimes that says "Drag to change the preferred order". You should reverse the order of the two first items or, if you are positive there will be no side effect, uncheck the two Java SE 5.

After it's done, typing `java -version` in a new terminal window should show that you run Java SE 6. After relaunching TextMate, does <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> work?

If not, the problem may come from the Java bundle and you'll have to search for some hardlinked or hardcoded reference to the old Java SE.